# How to Change the font of DropDown list (Combobox) in Acrobat X

Tags: javascript, fonts, combobox

I'm not a scripter, so I'm asking here if anyone can help me with my problem.

I did a form in Indesign CC 2015 and when I export it, I found that the font used in text boxes and combo boxes is Adobe Arabic and take a strange character due it's RTL language.

I searched for how to change the font used in text fields and found a script run by the Action Wizard in Acrobat. After that, I tried for hours to search for similar code with a Dropdown list (Combobox) but I didn't find any.

could you please check the below script (i found it on the internet.), it should be searching for all the text fields and apply given font to them.

```js
/* Change to Font name */
for (var i = 0; i < numFields; i++) {
  var fName = getNthFieldName(i);
  var f = getField(fName);
  if (f.type === "text") {
    //      f.alignment ="center";
    f.textSize = 10;
    f.textFont = "arial";
    // Other properties go here
  }
}
```

I need it to include the combo boxes too.

Is that possible?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: In particular, it's worth noting that your deadlines are your own problem, and they cannot be summarily transferred to volunteers. Readers may help you, and if they do, it will be at their leisure.